# Browser windows in the background are not getting RAM/CPU to work properly

Tags: windows, google-chrome, memory, browser, google-chrome-extensions

I use an extension I developed to automate some tasks on certain websites. I need to run at least 40 browsers with the automation extension enabled.

Now the problem is only the browser thats open in the front and visible on the screen is working fine.
All the other ones in the background are not.
So I need to open all browsers next to each other so that a small part of them are visible to fix this problem.
This is quite annoying.

Why are the browsers that are not open on the screen not getting attention from my CPU/RAM or whatever.

How can I force my PC to give them the same attention as the ones that are visible on the screen? I'm looking for is something like Tetsujin was referring to, a switch that priortizes the background apps the same as the foreground apps.

Comment: There used to be a simple switch in Windows to prioritise foreground apps or background tasks. idk if it's still there in 10/11.

Comment: @Peregrino69 I developed that extension myself so it can't be done any other way.
What I'm looking for is something like Tetsujin was refeering to, a switch that priortises the background apps the same as the foreground apps.

Comment: Of course it can be done another way: Using "proper" browser automation tools (Selenium WebDriver, Playwright).

Comment: @Peregrino69 I mean yes it could be done another way haha
Selenium would be a good option actually, will look into that.
But a lot of work to develop it.

Was hoping for a more simply solution

Comment: As luck has it, [another similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/1776830/allocate-the-same-cpu-resources-to-minimized-chrome-as-if-it-were-maximized) just popped up. There's an answer with one way around.